# Missing connection string in Azure Search data source

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using Azure Search API to PUT Data Source:

```
"name" : "XXX",
"type" : "azuresql",
"credentials" : { "connectionString" : "Server=tcp:XXX.database.windows.net,1433;Database=XXX;User ID=XXX@XXX;Password=XXX;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=600;" },
"container" : { "name" : "[dbo].[v_XXX]" },
"dataChangeDetectionPolicy" : { "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy", "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "rowVersion" }
```

and the Data Source gets created, but when I try to GET Data Source it's missing connection string value:

```
"@odata.context": "https://XXX.search.windows.net/$metadata#datasources/$entity",
"name": "XXX",
"description": null,
"type": "azuresql",
"credentials": {
    "connectionString": null
},
"container": {
    "name": "[dbo].[v_XXX]",
    "query": null
},
"dataChangeDetectionPolicy": {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
    "highWaterMarkColumnName": "rowVersion"
},
"dataDeletionDetectionPolicy": null
```

which (I suppose) leads me to the following error during indexers process:

```
"status": "transientFailure",
"errorMessage": "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
```

How can I verify what's causing the missing connection string problem?

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I PUT/POST Data Source I see connection string in the response from the API.

Comment: Did you check on portal if your index is already available?

Comment: Also, take a look at the following link. It helped me when I was trying Azure Search http://devslice.net/2015/03/azure-search-indexers-index-data-without-writing-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on Azure Search. This is actually by design - we thought that connection strings are too sensitive to be able to retrieve them with a GET. We do return them at POST / PUT time to accurately represent the resource that's just been created.

We're open to feedback on this usability / security tradeoff. If you think you'd rather be able to retrieve the connection strings, please add a suggestion on [our UserVoice](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Thanks!

Eugene

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's reasonable, but I was misled by MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn946893.aspx.